# Recommendations for studying real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

I am trying to study Real Analysis with Folland's book, because I want to know about measure theories. But I felt it was a little difficult to me. I have a knowledge about basic analysis, and a bit of topology. If I want to understand well while studying on this book, on which parts do I have to study more or work on? Or if you think I chose a wrong book, can you recommend me other books to get a concept of measure theory?

Comment: I found Sheldon Axler's new book on Measure Theory much easier to follow than Folland.

Comment: Axler is a good author, and his real analysis book is free and available online.

Comment: I liked the book by Royden.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Folland's book but I would recommend Measure Theory by Donald L. Cohn 2ed or Maß und Integrationstheorie by Jürgen Elstrodt 7ed.

Edit: I am currently revising some measure and integration theory for an upcoming course and I am using a different book. Namely, "Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration (3rd Edition)" by J Yeh and it is a delight for self-studying. His exposition is clear and his proofs are detailed. Note also that there is a solution/proof manual "Problems And Proofs In Real Analysis: Theory Of Measure And Integration" by the same author. I've gone through chapter 1 of Yeh's book so far.

Comment: Could you tell me the advantages of those books? As a beginner, I want to look for a book that has nice explanations.

Comment: The book by Cohn is very self-study friendly. It gives lots of examples and has appendices on set theory, algebra and basic facts about $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, about the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, about topological spaces and metric spaces and more. The Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is constructed in the first chapter and is then used as the basic example for the subsequent chapters. From the preface of the book:

Comment: "This book is intended as a straightforward treatment of the parts of measure
theory necessary for analysis and probability. The first five or six chapters form an
introduction to measure and integration, while the last three chapters should provide
the reader with some tools that are necessary for study and research in any of a
number of directions."

Comment: Elstrodt's book is a bit more dense and contains much more abstract constructions and minimalism in the sense that everything is packaged up as minimal as possible and from that the theory is constructed. I personally use Elstrodt as a reference and was using it as a supplement whenever I needed a second exposition or things which weren't in Cohn.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment!!!

Comment: However, I searched for the book of Elstrodt's, but I guess it's written in German..... Is there an English version?

Comment: No it's only in German. Should've mentioned that.

Comment: @19017김범준 See my edit.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write an answer :( It's too sad that I can't read German... Anyway, thank you for your comments :):)